# Delete equal data from two tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-delete

I have 2 tables with these columns:

Table A

```
Id | Name  | Salary  
1  | TEST1 | 100  
2  | TEST2 | 200  
3  | TEST3 | 300
```

Table B

```
Id | Name  | Salary  
1  | TEST1 | 100  
2  | TEST2 | 200  
4  | TEST4 | 400
```

I want to delete similar data from two tables (without using joins). When I query

```
SELECT * 
FROM A 

SELECT * 
FROM B
```

I should get this result:

Table A

```
Id | Name  | Salary   
3  | TEST3 | 300
```

Table B

```
Id | Name  | Salary   
4  | TEST4 | 400
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

PS : I'm going to load the table with around 10 millions rows

Comment: Similiar:  only id or all fields? What if `TableB` has `1 TEST1 101`?

Comment: It should be all fields

Comment: @RajuVadnala - Mysql <> Sql Server which one you are using

Comment: Then that should come in select * from A result

Comment: Why wouldn't you just create a new table with the non-duplicated rows from each table?  Deleting millions of rows from tables is expensive and doesn't seem particularly useful for most applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You better replace *"delete lots of rows"* to *"create a new table with only those rows remaining"*.

Very simple if your SQL Server version supports `EXCEPT`:

```
SELECT * INTO newA FROM a
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM b
;

SELECT * INTO newB FROM b
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM a
;
```

See [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/001b5/5)

`EXISTS` also simplifies `NULL` treatment.

Comment: Create new table  it is very easy. But what with foreign key constraints/CASDACE DELETE and so on?

Comment: @lad2025: OP wants to: *"compare two data files. the file size may be around 3 gb having records more than 10 million . I need to load the file into tables and delete similar data"*

Comment: And OP provided very simplified version with 3 dummy columns. And how would you know that delete ratio will be 95% and not 5%?

Comment: @lad2025: See the same comment on your solution, OP: *"what if the data being deleted in millions ?"*

Comment: But my point is that in general creating new table is not always possible. It is not as simple as create new table, drop old and rename new to old. Maybe it will work for this particular scenario, in general it depends :)

Comment: @lad2025: Of course in general recreating a table is not always possible, but in this case I prefer a simple solution with an easy syntax. Btw, `SELECT INTO` is minimally logged.

Answer (score 3):

Use `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT * 
FROM   a 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                   FROM   b 
                   WHERE  a.id = b.id) 

SELECT * 
FROM   b 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                   FROM   a 
                   WHERE  a.id = b.id)
```

For all the field's use `EXCEPT`

```
SELECT Id, Name, Salary FROM A
EXCEPT
SELECT Id, Name, Salary FROM B

SELECT Id, Name, Salary FROM B
EXCEPT
SELECT Id, Name, Salary FROM A
```

To delete the records from `tablea` use the below query

```
WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT * 
         FROM   tablea a 
         WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                        FROM   tableb b 
                        WHERE  a.id = b.id 
                               AND a.NAME = b.NAME 
                               AND a.salary = b.salary)) 
DELETE FROM cte 

SELECT * 
FROM   tablea
```

Before deleting the data from `tableA` insert the data into temp table to refer when deleting data from `tableB`

Comment: Why only based on `id`? And not entire row?

Comment: I'm comparing complete row data, not with primary key. Ideally all columns should be joined, since i have lot of columns for my table, i'm gonna avoid joins.

Comment: @RajuVadnala - first clarify which RDBMS you are using

Comment: Did you notice that OP wants to delete data? `I want to delete similar data from two tables` Not select

Comment: I tried the above except query, it works great, But i specifically want to delete those records from my tables.

Comment: @lad2025 ,@VR46 Its sql server not my sql.

Comment: And what with tableB?

Comment: I guess you don't get the point. When you delete FROM A, you will get different data to compare with table B. Check my answer (I stored intermediate data in temp table)

Comment: Yep, that looks good but i want to load the tables with 10 million rows. Will it sound good to load that much into one more table to do the deletion?

Answer (score 1):

Use `DELETE FROM`:

```
SELECT *
INTO #temp
FROM TableA;    -- to get the same data to compare with second DELETE

DELETE t
FROM TableA t
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT Id,Name,Salary
             FROM TableB
             INTERSECT
             SELECT t.ID, t.Name, t.Salary);

DELETE t
FROM TableB t
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT Id,Name,Salary
             FROM #temp
             INTERSECT
             SELECT t.ID, t.Name, t.Salary);  


SELECT * FROM TableA;
SELECT * FROM TableB;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/424459)**</kbd>

Output:

```
 TableA:
╔════╦═══════╦════════╗
║ Id ║ Name  ║ Salary ║
╠════╬═══════╬════════╣
║  3 ║ TEST3 ║    300 ║
╚════╩═══════╩════════╝


TableB:
╔════╦═══════╦════════╗
║ Id ║ Name  ║ Salary ║
╠════╬═══════╬════════╣
║  4 ║ TEST4 ║    400 ║
╚════╩═══════╩════════╝
```

**EDIT:**

To avoid coping entire table use `OUTPUT` clause;

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(ID INT, NAME VARCHAR(100), Salaray INT);

DELETE t
OUTPUT deleted.Id, deleted.Name, deleted.Salary
INTO #temp
FROM TableA t
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT Id,Name,Salary
             FROM TableB
             INTERSECT
             SELECT t.ID, t.Name, t.Salary);

DELETE t
FROM TableB t
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT Id,Name,Salary 
             FROM (SELECT Id,Name,Salary FROM TableA
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT Id,Name,Salary FROM #temp) AS sub
             INTERSECT
             SELECT t.ID, t.Name, t.Salary);
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/424463#resultSets)**</kbd>

To avoid delete problems (log growth, tempdb pressure and so on) you could process data using 100k chunk each. Add `WHILE LOOP` with 2 variables `@range_start, @range_stop` and increment by 100k or any other  value that suits your system.

Comment: Thats really great, thank you, but how about deleting same data from B ?

Comment: Yep, that looks good but i want to load the tables with 10 million rows. Will it sound good to load that much into one more table to do the deletion?

Comment: Yes, but what if the data being deleted in millions ? Actually i need to compare two data files. the file size may be around 3 gb having records more than 10 million . I need to load the file into tables and delete similar data.

Comment: Is your `ID` unique. Probably yes. Do the process with 100k chunks each.

Comment: Yes, i have faced log growth problem. I need to delete them in batches. Thanks for your suggestion.